# memory exhausted : for large files using diff

Tags: diff, patch, large-files

I am trying to create a patch using two large size folders (~7GB).

Here is how I'm doing it :

```
$ diff -Naurbw . ../other-folder > file.patch
```

But maybe due to file sizes, patch is not getting created and giving an error:

```
diff: memory exhausted
```

I tried making space more than 15 GB but still the issue persists. Could someone help me out with the flags that I should use?

Comment: yes, i'd tried googling it and found some parameter changes and the "memory exhausted" error is still there, even if using "--speed-large-files" flag.

Comment: How about diffing them in multiple steps? e.g. split the folders into, say, 1GB blocks, diff, then concatenate the patch, though I'm not sure if diff can be split like that (so you might need some extra logic to apply the patch). Why are you diffing 7GB folders in the first place? Surely only some files/folders inside it have changed?

Comment: yes, i tried diffing them separately and creating differebt patches abd merging them but the patch does not get applied. While creating a single patch size of patch goes to 800KB but after merging it becomes 90KB and it's not getting applied.

Comment: @pritam check out my answer above, sir

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Recently I came across this too when I needed to diff two large files (>5Gb each).

I tried to use 'diff' with different options, but even the `--speed-large-files` had no effect. Other methods like splitting the files into smaller ones, using `xdelta` or sorting the files as per [this suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2150/diffing-two-big-text-files) didn't help either. I even got my hands around a very powerful VM (> 72Gb RAM), but still got this `memory exhausted` error.

I finally got to work by adding the following parameter to `sysctl.conf` (`sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf`):

```
vm.overcommit_memory=1
```

`vm.overcommit_memory` has three values (0,1,2) and sets the kernel virtual memory accounting mode. From the [proc(5) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html):

> 0: heuristic overcommit (this is the default)
>   1: always overcommit, never check
>   2: always check, never overcommit

To make sure that the parameter is indeed applied you can run

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Don't forget to change this parameter back when you finish!

Comment: I agree, interesting, non-standard, and it worked for me! Comparing two 70GB files, I see e.g. 317TB virtual and 150TB resident RAM... a comparison that could not run before even with 250GB RAM now completes. Very clever!

Comment: Excelent, also you can add swap space 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/349156/how-to-use-hard-disk-as-ram-like-in-windows

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me like this: 
```cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory```, 
```echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory```, diff, ```echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory```, ```cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory```

Answer (score 2):

`bsdiff` is slow & requires large memory, `xdelta` is create large delta for large files.

Try HDiffPatch for large files: https://github.com/sisong/HDiffPatch

- support diff between large binary files or directories;
- can run on: Windows, macos, Linux, Android
- diff & patch both support run with limit memory;

Usage example:

- Creating a patch: `hdiffz -s-256 [-c-lzma2] old_path new_path out_delta_file`
- Applying a patch: `hpatchz old_path delta_file out_new_path`

Answer (score -3):

Try `sdiff`. It's a pre-built tool in some Linux Distributions.

```
sdiff a.txt b.txt --output=c.txt
```

will show the files to be Modified.

This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: How exactly does sdiff use less memory on large files than diff?

Comment: This doesn't work for large files. I got the same error as I got with diff

Comment: apparently it just uses diff giving...  diff: memory exhausted