# Diff very large files with constant space (memory limit)

Tags: diff, large-files

I would like to diff two very large database dumps (several 200 Gb tabular files) in a limited-memory Linux environment (16 Gb RAM). The changes between the two files I am comparing are sparse and they are expected to retain the same order (one may assume they are sorted, though they are not).

Searching for answers online ([[1]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2150/diffing-two-big-text-files),[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264062/memory-exhausted-for-large-files-using-diff),[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714810/diff-of-two-very-large-text-files)), led me to try `diff --speed-large-files` -- but I am still hitting the memory limit (further along the file, it appears, but I am still not getting any output). I am unwilling to change the kernel overcommit behavior like one answer suggested.[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264062/memory-exhausted-for-large-files-using-diff)

I would like to be able to specify a memory limit for the diff. I am willing to pay in a less-precise diff result.

I would imagine that there should be some kind of diff algorithm that compares a block of data at a time, spitting out the difference as it goes, with the risk of losing sync, which I assume it will not lose as long as the block size is much larger than the common distance between modifications. However, I am unable to find such an algorithm -- the closest I got are some academic papers.([[4]](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-46541-3_16),[[5]](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/S0097539799361701))

Is there such an existing, readily-available command-line utility for Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I found that xdelta (a VCDIFF implementation, and possibly other binary-geared diff implementations), actually mentioned in some of the answers to questions I mentioned, have constant-space behavior out of the box. I was relieved to this mentioned in the RFC 3284:

> A common way to deal with memory limitation is to partition an
>   input file into chunks called "windows" and process them
>   separately.  Here, except for unpublished work by Vo, little has been
>   done on designing effective windowing schemes.  Current techniques,
>   including Vdelta, simply use source and target windows with
>   corresponding addresses across source and target files.

So they might actually suit my goal, though their output isn't textual.

Before I found this, and since I couldn't find any ready-made text-based implementation, I implemented my own "windowed diff" using Python's difflib and thought I would share with the world.

I added some basic output options and testing code, but note that this was not tested beyond what you read below, so use at your own risk. *The code fails on the assertion on my real life case -- hopefully someone has a neater solution.*

```
import difflib
import itertools
import unittest

# thanks to https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)


class Missing:
    """
    Utility class that may be used to nicely represent a 'missing' value.
    """
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<missing>'

    def __sizeof__(self):
        return 0

    def __hash__(self):
        return 0


def rindex_predicate(seq, pred):
    """
    Find the next-to right-most index, such that for items following this index the given predicate holds.

    e.g. rindex_predicate([1, 2], lambda x: x>2) -> 1
         rindex_predicate([1, 2], lambda x: x>1) -> 0
         rindex_predicate([1, 2], lambda x: x>0) -> -1
    """
    i = len(seq) - 1
    while i >= 0 and pred(seq[i]):
        i -= 1
    return i


def rsplit_predicate(seq, pred):
    """
    Split the sequence to two, so that the second part consists only of items for which the predicate holds,
    and the predicate does not hold for the last item of the first part (if it exists).

    e.g. rsplit_predicate([1,2,3], lambda x: x>2) -> ([1,2], [3])
    """
    i = rindex_predicate(seq, pred)
    if i == len(seq) - 1:
        return seq, []
    if i == -1:
        return [], seq
    return seq[:i+1], seq[i+1:]


def windowed_diff(seq1, seq2, window_size):
    """
    Performs a diff of two sequences, similar to SequenceMatcher, using constant space (limited memory)
    determined by window_size. As opposed to SequenceMatcher, the sequences may be generators.

    This is done by breaking the sequences up to windows. Each pair of windows is compared almost independently.
    By allowing tails of unmatched items in one window to be compared on the following window, synchronization 
    problems that result from the window size may be partially avoided. However, if the synchornization is lost
    for a length beyond the given window_size, the diff algorithm might not be able to regain it as it would
    if a full-memory diff was used.

    Returns a generator which generates a tuple (a, b, opcodes) where a and b are the respective windows
    being compared, and opcodes are what SequenceMatcher.get_opcodes() would return with respect to these
    windows.
    """

    # some utilities
    missing = Missing()
    missing_group = tuple()

    is_missing = lambda x: x is missing
    def isnt_equal(opcode):
        tag, alo, ahi, blo, bhi = opcode
        return tag != 'equal'

    # get windows ready
    groups1 = grouper(seq1, window_size, fillvalue=missing)
    groups2 = grouper(seq2, window_size, fillvalue=missing)
    tail1, tail2 = [], []
    overflow1, overflow2 = [], []
    tail = []
    pos1, pos2 = 0, 0

    for group1, group2 in itertools.zip_longest(groups1, groups2, fillvalue=missing_group):
        assert len(tail1) <= (window_size*2) and len(tail2) <= (window_size*2)

        # we prepend any previous unmatched items (see tail below)
        window1, window2 = tuple(tail1) + group1, tuple(tail2) + group2

        window1, _ = rsplit_predicate(window1, is_missing)
        window2, _ = rsplit_predicate(window2, is_missing)

        # don't let the window size overflow
        # we save the overflow of the window and append it to the tail later
        # the largest left-hand part of the window becomes resolved as we
        # look for the right-most equal opcode
        # this means that any added tail will not contain an equal opcode
        # if the tail happens to exceed window_size and contains no equal opcode,
        # since it is prepended to the subsequent window, in the next cycle that
        # entire window will be resolved by out-of-sync test below, and no new
        # items will be added to tail, keeping the size of tail in check
        tail1, tail2 = [], []
        overflow1, overflow2 = window1[window_size:], window2[window_size:]
        window1, window2 = window1[:window_size], window2[:window_size]

        cruncher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(isjunk=None, a=window1, b=window2)
        opcodes = list(cruncher.get_opcodes())

        # the tail is whatever didn't match at the end of the window
        resolved, tail = rsplit_predicate(opcodes, isnt_equal)

        if not resolved:
            # no items are equal - we are out of sync
            # resolve all opcodes and move on
            resolved = tail
            tail = []

        # matches up to the last equal (synchronization) point are yielded to caller
        yield pos1, pos2, window1, window2, resolved

        # push any discrepencies at end of window to next block
        for tag, alo, ahi, blo, bhi in tail:
            if tag == 'delete':
                # it was in block1 but not in block2
                tail1 += window1[alo:ahi]
            elif tag == 'insert':
                tail2 += window2[blo:bhi]
            elif tag == 'replace':
                tail1 += window1[alo:ahi]
                tail2 += window2[blo:bhi]
            else:
                raise ValueError(tag)

        tail1 += list(overflow1)
        tail2 += list(overflow2)

        pos1 += len(window1) - len(tail1)
        pos2 += len(window2) - len(tail2)

    # flush out last tail
    if overflow1:
        window1 += overflow1
    if overflow2:
        window2 += overflow2

    if tail or overflow1 or overflow2:
        # re-evaluate last window, minus resolved
        _, alo, ahi, blo, bhi = resolved[-1]
        window1 = window1[ahi:]
        window2 = window2[bhi:]

        # pos1,2 were already updated at end of previous loop

        cruncher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(isjunk=None, a=window1, b=window2)
        opcodes = list(cruncher.get_opcodes())

        yield pos1, pos2, window1, window2, opcodes


# based on difflib code (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/difflib.py)
def windowed_text_diff(a, b, window_size):
    """
    Same as difflib.Differ().compare(), only using windowed_diff instead of SequenceMatcher.
    """
    differ = difflib.Differ()
    for apos, bpos, a, b, opcodes in windowed_diff(a, b, window_size):
        for tag, alo, ahi, blo, bhi in opcodes:
            if tag == 'replace':
                g = differ._fancy_replace(a, alo, ahi, b, blo, bhi)
            elif tag == 'delete':
                g = differ._dump('-', a, alo, ahi)
            elif tag == 'insert':
                g = differ._dump('+', b, blo, bhi)
            elif tag == 'equal':
                g = differ._dump(' ', a, alo, ahi)
            else:
                raise ValueError('unknown tag %r' % (tag,))

            yield from g


def unified_diff_from_grouped_opcodes(a, b, apos, bpos, grouped_opcodes, lineterm='\n'):
    """
    Same as difflib.unified_diff, only the grouped_opcodes are given, no file info is given and no type checks are done.
    """
    for group in grouped_opcodes:
        first, last = group[0], group[-1]
        file1_range = difflib._format_range_unified(first[1]+apos, last[2]+apos)
        file2_range = difflib._format_range_unified(first[3]+bpos, last[4]+bpos)
        yield '@@ -{} +{} @@{}'.format(file1_range, file2_range, lineterm)

        for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in group:
            if tag == 'equal':
                for line in a[i1:i2]:
                    yield ' ' + line
                continue
            if tag in {'replace', 'delete'}:
                for line in a[i1:i2]:
                    yield '-' + line
            if tag in {'replace', 'insert'}:
                for line in b[j1:j2]:
                    yield '+' + line


def windowed_unified_diff(a, b, window_size, fromfile='', tofile='', fromfiledate='',
                 tofiledate='', n=3, lineterm='\n'):
    started = False
    for apos, bpos, a, b, opcodes in windowed_diff(a, b, window_size):
        if not started:
            started = True
            fromdate = '\t{}'.format(fromfiledate) if fromfiledate else ''
            todate = '\t{}'.format(tofiledate) if tofiledate else ''
            yield '--- {}{}{}'.format(fromfile, fromdate, lineterm)
            yield '+++ {}{}{}'.format(tofile, todate, lineterm)

        matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b)
        matcher.opcodes = opcodes
        grouped_opcodes = matcher.get_grouped_opcodes(n)
        yield from unified_diff_from_grouped_opcodes(a, b, apos, bpos, grouped_opcodes, lineterm=lineterm)


class WindowedDiffTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_windowed_diff(self):
        import random

        def generate_lines(n, prob_mutation):
            if prob_mutation == 0:
                return ('%d' % (i,) for i in range(n))

            for i in range(n):
                if random.random() < prob_mutation:
                    action = random.choice(['insert', 'delete', 'edit'])
                    if action == 'insert':
                        yield 'inserted at %d' % (i,)
                    elif action == 'delete':
                        continue
                    elif action == 'edit':
                        yield '%d+' % (i,)
                        continue
                yield '%d' % (i,)

        for subtest1 in itertools.product(
            ['a', 'b', 'neither'], # cut
            [False, True], # append
            [False, True], # prepend
            [15, 16], # n
            range(0, 100, 30), # pct_mutation
            range(1, 10) # seed
        ):
            cut, append, prepend, n, pct_mutation, seed = subtest1

            prob_mutation = pct_mutation/100.0

            random.seed(seed)
            a = list(generate_lines(n, prob_mutation=0))
            b = list(generate_lines(n, prob_mutation=prob_mutation))

            if cut == 'a':
                a = a[:int(n*0.9)]
            elif cut == 'b':
                b = b[:int(n*0.8)]

            if append:
                a += ['@' * (1+(i%int(n/2))) for i in range(n*2)]
                b += ['!' * (2+(i%(int(n/2)+1))) for i in range(n*2)]
            if prepend:
                a = ['@' * (1+(i%int(n/2))) for i in range(n*2)] + a
                b = ['!' * (2+(i%(int(n/2)+1))) for i in range(n*2)] + b

            base_text_diff_result = list(difflib.ndiff(a, b))
            base_unified_diff_result = list(difflib.unified_diff(a, b, n=0))
            base_opcodes = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).get_opcodes()

            for window_size in set([1, 2, 3, 4, int(n/2)-1, int(n/2), n-1, n, n+1, n*2]):
                subtest = subtest1 + (window_size,)

                with self.subTest(subtest):
                    result = list(windowed_text_diff(a=(x for x in a), b=(x for x in b), window_size=window_size))
                    self.assertEqual(list(difflib.restore(result, 1)), a, result)
                    self.assertEqual(list(difflib.restore(result, 2)), b, result)


def main():
    import argparse
    import sys

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--window-size', type=int, default=1024*64)
    parser.add_argument('--unified-diff', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--context', type=int, default=3)
    parser.add_argument('file1')
    parser.add_argument('file2')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    with open(args.file1, 'rt') as f1, open(args.file2, 'rt') as f2:
        if args.unified_diff:
            result = windowed_unified_diff(f1, f2, args.window_size, n=args.context, fromfile=f1.name, tofile=f2.name)
        else:
            result = windowed_text_diff(f1, f2, args.window_size)

        for line in result:
            sys.stdout.write(line)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

try HDiffPatch: https://github.com/sisong/HDiffPatch
tested diff between 50GB files (no test with 200GB)
(bsdiff is slow & requires large memroy; xdelta is create large delta for large files; )

it can run on: windows,macos,linux,android
support diff between large binary files or directories;
diff & patch both support run with limit memory;
Creating a patch: `hdiffz -s-4k [-c-zlib] old_path new_path out_delta_file`
Applying a patch: `hpatchz old_path delta_file out_new_path`

"-s-4k" is means diff by Stream block,and a block is 4096 bytes;
(diff principle is to clip the old data to blocks by blockSize, calculate block's hash save to a hash table, and then use the roll-hash algorithm on  new data to match it's in table)
input 200GB file requires ~ 200GB*16/4k < 1GB bytes of memory; if diff with "-s-256k" then less time & less memory;